API Management - make set-query-parameter work in a case insensitive way
We have an API configured in API Manager, with some product and policies. One of the policies tries to ensure that some queryparameter is always set to a specific value.
<set-query-parameter name="myParameter" exists-action="override">
<value>myFixedValue</value>
</set-query-parameter>

This works fine, until someone add the same parameter with different casing, eg. MyParameter, or mYpAraMeTeR, in that case the set-query-parameter policy is ignored, because it is case sensitive.
Is there a way to ensure this policy is correctly applied, in a case-insensitive way?
After some searching I found the policy validate-parameters which I was hoping would be of help, but I haven't found the magic combination of properties as of yet.
<validate-parameters specified-parameter-action="ignore" unspecified-parameter-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="validationErrors">
    <headers specified-parameter-action="ignore" unspecified-parameter-action="ignore"/>
    <query specified-parameter-action="ignore" unspecified-parameter-action="prevent">
        <parameter name="myParameter" action="ignore" />
    </query>
    <path specified-parameter-action="ignore"/>
</validate-parameters>

I was hoping this would just pass on all headers and path supplied, but limit the allowed query parameters to only myParameter
Hoping someone with a bit more APIM knowledge can help me out :)

It looks like validate-parameters  is also case sensitive.
Correct policy definition would be-
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <validate-parameters specified-parameter-action="ignore" unspecified-parameter-action="prevent" errors-variable-name="requestParametersValidation">
            <headers specified-parameter-action="ignore" unspecified-parameter-action="ignore" />
            <query specified-parameter-action="ignore" unspecified-parameter-action="prevent">
                <parameter name="myParameter" action="ignore" />
            </query>
        </validate-parameters>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

But it will give you error if you are passing any other value than myParameter parameter. It won't work for case values of myParameter.


So, alternatively I am using below policy which works only for myParameter but not for any other combination of myParameter parameter.
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <base />
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.TryGetValue("myParameter", out var value) && value.Any(v => string.Equals(v, "myFixedValue", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))" />
            <otherwise>
                <return-response>
                    <set-status code="400" reason="Bad Request" />
                    <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
                        <value>text/plain</value>
                    </set-header>
                    <set-body>@("Only the 'myParameter' query parameter is allowed.")</set-body>
                </return-response>
            </otherwise>
        </choose>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>

Output-




Trace-


After some discussion in our team it turned out that for this product it was never allowed for users to provide a custom value for myParameter, so for now we settled for the following solution:
<when condition='@(context.Request.Url.Query.Keys.Contains("organisatieonderdeelIds", StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == true)'>      <return-response>         <set-status code="400" reason="Bad request - unsupported parameter provided"/>       </return-response></when>
